# Duplicate a row with data changing

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with several columns. on some conditions I run a script that duplicates the row.

This is done via these steps:

1. select all columns from the row to be duplicated
2. on the resulting array change two values out of 30 (new info are built on the fly using php scripts and are unique for the row). **these values can be created any time during the update process**
3. insert the new row with the usual `insert into...` that make me list again all the 30 fields and values

My question is: is there a way to change this script into:

1. create the new values
2. run a single query that will duplicate the row and at the same time update the values while duplicating?

So that i don't need to manipulate the array in php and I run just one query instead of two?

Comment: showing some tables and sample data wouldn't break our hearts

Comment: It's not simple to add the code actually (writing from iPad) Anyway table is made of varchar and decimal fields only and the queries are just select and insert into run via PDO. not that much added value I think! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a single query, but you will need to list all the fields:

```
INSERT INTO your_table
SELECT
   NULL, #in place of auto-increment column (if any)
   'some value for the field you want to change',
   'some value for another field you want to change',
   not_changed_field1,
   not_changed_field2,
   ...
FROM your_table
WHERE <row has to be duplicated>
```